# How to extract UNC path of all shares available in a server?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012

Please someone help me to create a batch file though which I can extract the UNC path of all shares available in one server.
Its very tedious to manually find out from server manager as I have to open properties of every share folder and take the UNC path from it.
Is there any specific powershell command or a batch script which I can run to extract for all available share folders.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can do it in batch with `net share`

Answer (score 2):

Get it from wmi

```
wmic /node:yourServer share get name,path /format:csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use WMI specifically WIN32_Share to get Share Name, Path, and Description, then pipe the reply into a loop.  Format the output to provide the UNC path, or send the output to a file

```
$SrvName = "YourServer"

gwmi -class win32_share -computer $SrvName | ForEach-Object {("\\"+$SrvName + "\" + $_.Name)}
```